# Get jsFiddle result iframe source code with php

Tags: javascript, php, curl, file-get-contents, jsfiddle

I have a jsFiddle that lives a happy life at https://fiddle.jshell.net/DelightedDoD/yu6nekv4/show/light/

If I navigate to `view-source:https://fiddle.jshell.net/DelightedDoD/yu6nekv4/show/light/` I can view the full rendered source code for my fiddle.

I need to get this full rendered source code in a php script.

Here is what I've tried:

#### file_get_contents():

```
$src = file_get_contents('https://fiddle.jshell.net/DelightedDoD/yu6nekv4/show/light/');
echo '<textarea>'.$src.'</textarea>';
```

#### curl:

```
$ch = curl_init('https://fiddle.jshell.net/DelightedDoD/yu6nekv4/show/light/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo '<textarea>'.$content.'</textarea>';
```

In both cases what I end up with is the *source code of the page that renders my fiddle's source code into an iFrame* **not** the *source code of my actual fiddle*

To see the result, go to http://dodsoftware.com/shared-resources/php/jsfiddle-mobile-bs-frame.php

#### Is there some way, I can replicate the result I get with `view-source:` using PHP or at least get the value then send it to my php script?

Comment: What happens if you curl `view-source:https://fiddle.jshell.net/DelightedDoD/yu6nekv4/show/light/`

Comment: @Rayon unfortunately I get [Warning: curl_error(): 2 is not a valid cURL handle resource](http://dodsoftware.com/shared-resources/php/jsfiddle-mobile-bs-frame2.php) Im assuming `view-source:` is a browser construct that curl doesnt understand

Comment: what do you get if you wget "https://fiddle.jshell.net/DelightedDoD/yu6nekv4/show/light/" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the **referer** in the curl options to the same page you are loading:

```
$url = 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/DelightedDoD/yu6nekv4/show/light/';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo '<textarea>'.$content.'</textarea>';
```

Comment: Yep, that does it. Would you mind briefly explaining *why* we need to set the referer? I read over [this](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_REFERER.html) but it's not immediately clear. Im  guessing it's so the server will see the info in the url it needs to create content or direct it to the correct endpoint?

Comment: @DelightedD0D - I can only make a guess and say that there is probably something server side on jshell.net that checks the referer and serves up the iframe content accordingly since it has the same `src` url as the page itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://fiddle.jshell.net/DelightedDoD/yu6nekv4/show/light/"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
$headers[] = 'Referer: http://fiddle.jshell.net/DelightedDoD/yu6nekv4/show/light/';
$headers[] = 'DNT: 1';
$headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8';
$headers[] = 'Cache-Control: max-age=0';
// $headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch';
$headers[] = 'Host: fiddle.jshell.net';
$headers[] = 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1';

$headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.10 Safari/537.36';


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

echo '<textarea>'.$server_output .'</textarea>';
```

Comment: This seems to create encoded or currupted output, see http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/8kvm-iveu and press "run"

Comment: Oh correct, that's because of the gzip encoding header, removing it will solve the problem, but the solution is the same as billynoah which is to consider the referer.

Comment: @vp_arth what do you mean?